# Convert Kotlin Unit to Java Void

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-binding

I am using [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) for Android widgets. I would like to do the following: `Observable<java.lang.Void> obs = RxView.clicks(button);`
But I get a compile time error saying that the expected type is `kotlin.Unit`. `RxView.clicks(button)` returns an `Observable<Unit>`but I don't think that Java has a Unit datatype.
 **How do I get an `Observable<Void>` in Java?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can live with `Observable<Unit>` in Java. `kotlin.Unit` is a class file available for java programs as soon as `kotlin-stdlib-<some version>.jar` is in your class path, and it is there already because it is required by RxBinding.

If, however, some other part of your program requires `Observable<Void>`, it can be obtained with:

```
 Observable<Unit> ou = RxView.clicks(button);
 Observable<Void> ov = ou.as(unit->null);
```

Comment: It looks like RxBinding library uses RxJava 1. I am trying to get a `Single<Void>` out of it and hence I thought that it would be better to have a `Void` type.